# Pulse width stretching of the 0 pulse with a constant T

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, pulse, schmitt-trigger, multivibrator

I have a digital output with varying pulse sizes and I want to design an IC to stretch the 0 output for a constant T+ "0" pulse time (as in attached picture).

[image: Signal output]

I have tried using a monostable multivibrator with a NAND gate but the problem I got is that the length of the pulse remains constant, which could be a problem if the pulse width is greater than the multivibrator output so how to add this time constant to the original pulse width instead?

Comment: There are two pulses in your question, the input pulse and the output pulse, but you keep talking about "the pulse". This is very confusing. Also, you need to specify the actual time values of the pulses you are talking about, as well as voltage levels.

Comment: Welcome to stack Exchange. How about a schematic of the circuit you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a grab from the innergoogle, from some old National Semiconductor publication. For your application, reverse D1 and place the R in parallel with the C. The first inverter also can be a 14 rather than an 04. The requirements for the gates is that they both be inverterrs, and that the second one must be a Schnitt Trigger type. Other than that, they can be any TTL or CMOS variety that matches the rest of your circuits.

A possible issue is that for some logic families, the pull up current capability is much less than the pull down. This means the first gate will have a harder time charging up the capacitor than in the original circuit where it is discharging the capacitor current down to GND. This will cause a delay in the leading edge of the output pulse.  If this is a problem, one solution is to use one of the newer, more "stiff" CMOS varieties like the AC or ACT series.

[image]